# Normalizacion de base de datos primera forma

Tags: sql

[image: Forma uno normalizacion base de datos]

Hola, tengo varias horas algo confundido con el tema de normalización de base de datos, creo que la forma que más se me complica es la segunda, no comprendo:

"Al examinar estos registros, podemos darnos cuenta que contienen un grupo repetido para NUM_ITEM, DESC_ITEM, CANT y PRECIO. La 1FN prohíbe los grupos repetidos, por lo tanto tenemos que convertir a la primera forma normal. Los pasos a seguir son:

Tenemos que eliminar los grupos repetidos."

Pero no entiendo por que NUM_ITEM, DESC_ITEM, CANT y PRECIO menciona que son repetidos, se refiere a que hay por ejemplo dos NUM_ITEM 4011 igual, dos DESC_ITEM Raqueta? es lo que tiene mas sentido para mi pero por ejemplo ID_CLIENTE repite varias veces 101 y 110 y en el ejemplo amteropr no menciona ese campo como repetido, lo cual me tiene muy confundido. Alguien podria ayudarme a comprenderlo un poco mejor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La pregunta es confusa, aunque me inclinaría a decir que es incorrecta. 
Pretende normalizar la tabla de ORDENES, y solo lo hace para algunas columnas, y con errores.

La tabla debería quedarse: ID_ORDEN, FECHA, ID_CLIENTE, ESTADO, NUM_ITEM, CANT

Tabla con FK: ARTICULOS_ORDENES: NUM_ITEM, PRECIO

Tabla con FK: CLIENTES: ID_CLIENTE, NOM_CLIENTE

Comment: Respuesta perfecta, pero le acabas de hacer los deberes :)

Comment: Estudio por mi propia cuenta, no es alguna tarea, de echo en el documento que leia al final viene resuelto pero me gusta comprender completamente las cosas aun que tenga la respuesta